# Go queue processing with retry on failure

Tags: asynchronous, go, redis, beanstalkd

We have a bunch of files to be uploaded to remote blob store after processing.

Currently, the frontend (PHP) creates a redis list of such files and gives it a unique ID, called JobID. It then passes the unique ID to a beanstalk tube, which is received by a Go process. It uses a library called Go [workers](https://github.com/mikegleasonjr/workers) to process each job ID in the fashion of what `net/http` does. It receives the job ID, retrieves the redis list and starts processing files.

However, currently only one file is processed at a time. Since the operation here is I/O bound, not CPU bound, intuition suggests that it would be benefitial to use a goroutine per file.

However, we want to retry uploading on failure, as well as track the number of items processed per job. We cannot start a unbound number of goroutines because a single Job can contain about ~10k files to process and 100s of such Jobs can be sent per second during peak times. What would be the correct approach for this?

NB: We can change the technology stack a bit if needed (such as swapping out beanstalkd for something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the number of goroutines by using a buffered `chan` with a size of the maximum number of goroutines you want. You can then block on this `chan` if it reaches maximum capacity. As your goroutines finish, they will free up slots to allow new goroutines to run.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var (
    concurrent    = 5
    semaphoreChan = make(chan struct{}, concurrent)
)

func doWork(wg *sync.WaitGroup, item int) {
    // block while full
    semaphoreChan <- struct{}{}

    go func() {
        defer func() {
            // read to release a slot
            <-semaphoreChan
            wg.Done()
        }()
        // This is where your work actually gets done
        fmt.Println(item)
    }()
}

func main() {
    // we need this for the example so that we can block until all goroutines finish
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(10)

    // start the work
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        doWork(&wg, i)
    }

    // block until all work is done
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Go Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/jDMYuCe7HV

Inspired by this Golang UK Conference talk: https://youtu.be/yeetIgNeIkc?t=1413

Comment: It helped me to get started on limiting the concurrency. However, the problem that still remained now is how to keep track of the success or failure of a job. A job contains N sub tasks, all of which must be processed successfully else errors needs to be reported. How do I approach to this ?

Comment: Create a channel that you pass to the goroutine. The goroutine can write the result of the operation, including errors to that channel. The caller can pull the info out of that channel handle the error as needed (eg. log the error or retry the operation). If you need to retry the operation, make the channel with a custom struct type with the necessary context to retry (eg. the input that the goroutine requires to try again) and an error.